# Open matchbox-keyboard on top of existing applications

Tags: pi-3, python

I have a Tkinter script running in fullscreen mode. I have a function which calls the `matchbox-keyboard` command using the `subprocess` module when clicked on an input field. This works fine, but the problem is that the keyboard opens behind the Tkinter window.

Is there any way to make the keyboard appear on top, maybe some configuration flags when calling the `matchbox-keyboard` command, or some setting in the Raspberry Pi?

I am using Python 3.4 and the target Raspbian OS is Jesse.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following section to `/etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml`, or whatever config file you are using, inside the `<applications>` section:

```
<application title="Keyboard">
    <layer>above</layer>
</application>
```

Also note that `matchbox-keyboard` supports embedding using `XReparentWindow()`, though I don't use Python much and have no idea which package you could use which provides the necessary bindings for Xlib. A quick google search suggests `python-xlib` may do this.

There are additional solutions discussed in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345224/x11-xlib-window-always-on-top), using either `XRaiseWindow()` call or `_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE` WM hint.

PS. I just tried it on my Pi. `_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE` [doesn't seem to work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256224/make-x11-window-always-on-top-virtual-keyboard/256262#256262). Editing the openbox rc file works fine though.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I found a bunch of XML files in `/usr/share/matchbox-keyboard/` . Is there something I can do here?

Comment: @RishiC Yes, you can change the keyboard layout there :) If you want the keyboard to be on the top layer, you need to configure the window manager. Check that you use openbox, and find out which config file is really used.

Comment: @RishiC My bad, you have to replace `name` with `title` in the config file.

Comment: This didn't work either. I guess I'm not editing the correct config file. I will look into it more and give an update if I manage to figure it out

Comment: @RishiC Yeah I'm on Buster and it's entirely possible that Jesse uses a different config file. Try running `ps ax | grep openbox`, maybe there's a config file specified on the command line. Or list all xml files with `find /etc /home | grep rc.xml` and try editing these.